# Mongo DB mongoose filter Array of ID Refer to other Schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I am trying to filter my content List collection based on the ID present in tags. But in my Rest API instead of sending Object ID query i want to filter based on tagId which is field of Tags Model. If any populated tag have a tagId then it return that content document.

I want to filter content if tags contain tagId which i am sending from front end.

```
const contentSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    tags: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Tag",
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);


const tagSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  tagId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    validate: function (value) {
      return !/\s/.test(value);
    },
    message: "Whitespace is not allowed in tagId",
  },
  tagName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
  },
});

const filterContentBasedOnGenres = async (res, tagId) => {
  const filteredContent = await Content.find({
    tags: { $elemMatch: { tagId: { $eq: tagId } } },
  }).populate("tags");

  return res.status(200).json(filteredContent);
};
```

So far i try this filterContentBasedOnGenres i want to filter content base on tagId which store inside tags.